# Input Field not working

Tags: php, html

I have a contact form on my website, and it takes data from a `<form>` element and then started it in a text file. However when I click submit it just opens the PHP script in a new tab.

HTML

```
  <form id="contact" action="action.php" method="post">
    <h3>Contact Form</h3>
    <h4>Contact me.</h4>
    <form action="action.php" method="post">

      <input type="text" name="field1" placeholder="Enter your name..."><br>
        <input type="email" name="field2" placeholder="Enter your email address..."><br>
       <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
```

PHP

```
<?php
 $path = 'data.txt';
 if (isset($_POST['field1']) && isset($_POST['field2'])) {
    $fh = fopen($path,"a+");
    $string = $_POST['field1'].' - '.$_POST['field2'];
    fwrite($fh,$string);
    fclose($fh)
 }

?>
```

Comment: Try the solution and let me know what's the output you are getting... This is a different way of putting it together. I see no issues with your code.

Comment: @PraveenKumar It doesnt output anything to the file and still opens the code in a new tab. Heres what the new tab looks like.

Comment: https://gyazo.com/fe6bf7e6a5b77706f6858a3d2c69b397

Comment: You're not running it on web server.

Comment: 2 opening form tags and 1 closing; there's your problem. and didn't close this off `fclose($fh)`

Comment: @Fred-ii- Yeah. But the first mistake is he doesn't run the script on localhost. PHP file is opened like that only when it is not run on web server. Check out his screenshot.

Comment: @Perumal93 that too; there are 2 errors in their code that I edited my comment about the missing closure

Comment: running this as `file:///` instead of `http://localhost`. when you do run as the latter, you'll get a bunch of errors.

Comment: Ok i ran it off local host and it saved the data, however it opened a new blank tab when i cliked submit, how do i stop that?

Comment: @mexO Remove one form tag and check.

Comment: Get it run on localhost first. Remove the nested form tag then and finally add semicolon to `fclose($fh)` so that should be like `fclose($fh);`.

Comment: I have done all that, now it works perfect apart from the face it opens a new blank tab when the submit button is clicked.

Comment: Did you remove the nested form tag? and the new tab issue is not about PHP script. There is some issue other than PHP script itself.

Comment: Heres the code noe

Comment: <h3>Contact Form</h3>
  <h4>Contact me.</h4>
  <form action="action.php" method="post">
    <input type="name" name="field1" placeholder="Enter your name..."><br>
    <input type="email" name="field2" placeholder="Enter your email address..."><br>
    <input type="text" name="field3" placeholder="Enter your message..."><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>

Comment: @Ionut You could provide him a reasonable solution because the solution you provided in the comment is a kind of unfair. Do you think leaving `action` attribute empty is going to resolve the problem? If it is removed, the data will be submitted to the same page itself. What if he wants to submit it to other page?

Comment: @mexO That's now a valid HTML code since you removed the nested form tag. So, you got it right now?

Comment: @Ionut He has some other issue. Maybe we need to check his whole code where something might be going wrong. By the way, I mentioned unfair not to offend you or anything. I just said that solution is not reasonable. `action` attribute should be mentioned if the form data has to be submitted to the page mentioned in the attribute.

Comment: I did too. It works. That's why I said he has some other issue in his code that makes his submission open in new tab.

Comment: @mexO I posted my answer 16 mins. prior to this comment http://stackoverflow.com/a/41307785/1415724 - outlining the errors and what you are doing wrong as to how you're running this. People are commenting here, but have yet to raise the fact about you running this as `file:///` such as I have [earlier in comments.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41307664/input-field-not-working/41307785#comment69818539_41307664)

Comment: @Ionut I actually mean the whole HTML code. Not the HTML code in the question. According to me, the only issue is in his HTML code is an additional form tag. I'm not even sure removing that extra form tag would resolve his new tab issue.

Comment: Like i said above and @lonut mentioned. Everything works fine now due to your guy's helpful solutions APART from the face when you enter some data it opens a new blank tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your screenshot [taken from comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41307664/input-field-not-working#comment69818462_41307664):

https://gyazo.com/fe6bf7e6a5b77706f6858a3d2c69b397

You're running this as `file:///` rather than `http://localhost` (make sure you do have php installed and a webserver installed on your machine). A web browser will not parse php directives as `file:///` unlike a web page using HTML.

You also have 2 errors.

2x opening `<form>` tags and 1 closing `</form>` (nested forms don't work in php) and the missing semi-colon in `fclose($fh)` which would throw a parse error such as:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}' ...

Once you run this as localhost, you're going to get errors about it.

Once you do correct the code, make sure that file has proper permissions to write to it and that the path is correct.

Use error reporting:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Plus, `<form id="contact"` (an id) suggests that you may be using JS for this; that is unknown. If so, then there may be an instance of `_blank` somewhere or JS for example: `onClick="window.open('path/to/file.php','windowname',' width=400,height=200')"`.

If it is opening in a new tab (as you say) once you click on submit, then something else is causing this which is also unknown to us.

- As an alternative, you could add `target="_top"` to `<form>`.

What you posted will not cause it to open in a new tab.

**NOTE:**

You will need to add either `\n` or `\r\n` (inside double quotes), or `PHP_EOL` to:

```
$string = $_POST['field1'].' - '.$_POST['field2'];
```

Otherwise, your data will keep writing to one continuous line.

I.e.:

```
$string = $_POST['field1'].' - '.$_POST['field2'] . "\n";
```

`\n` is for *NIX systems, `\r\n` on Windows and PHP_EOL being cross-platform.

Comment: I have no JS in this website. All i have is the PHP and the HTML/CSS. IT works fine now but it is still opening a new tab.

Comment: @mexO that is most perplexing. I Google'd for about 10 mins. trying to find out why that is. I noticed you're running this off of `F:` drive, that may be a reason. Is the (PHP) installation done on that same drive or on `C:`?

Comment: @mexO I also made another edit to my answer, stating to add `target="_top"` to `<form>`, see if that makes it stay on the same tab or `target="_self"`.

Comment: I tried both and neither work. You can visit the site at maxjordan.net to try and see for yourself if you want. I am 100% bamboozled.

Comment: So it didnt open a new tab?

Comment: @mexO It did not.

Comment: I see your input 

john - email@example.com - testing

So could it be because i have the php file on my PC?

Comment: @mexO Yep, that was me. It could be because of it, it's really hard to say.

Comment: Well thanks for the help! Im gonna test it on a few different devices and see what happens!